# Creating a test app to store first name, last name, username & password in to a db get odd results

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

On running the app I get the following error:

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'password' at row 1

I changed the table from `varchar (50)` to `longText` which has cured the data too long for column.

Result (Stored in db):

```
javax.swing.JPasswordField[,150,137,239x28,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@171f498,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=,disabledTextColor=DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145,editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=DerivedColor(color=255,255,255 parent=nimbusSelectedText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=255,255,255,selectionColor=DerivedColor(color=57,105,138 parent=nimbusSelectionBackground offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=57,105,138,columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,echoChar=*]
```

The resulting is stored in the db and not the password

Comment: You called `field.toString()` (or tried to pass `field` to a method that takes a `String`, which is the same thing); you need to call [`field.getPassword()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword()) (or `getText()`). The `toString` does not do what you might have thought it does.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
The mistake made was within my code. I had originally put ps.setString(4, newAccPass.toString()); in stead off ps.setString(4, String.valueOf(newAccPass.getPassword()));